# Erase free space with Terminal running IOS El Capitan 10.11.4

Tags: terminal, secure-erase

The Terminal command:  diskutil secureErase freespace 4 /volumes/”Macintosh HD” returns the “could not find disk HD” message.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize "Volumes":

```
diskutil secureErase freespace 4 "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"

diskutil secureErase freespace 4 /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

Edit: I see you already put "Macintosh HD" in quotes. Fixed above.

Comment: The command line w/ the quotes failed in the same way, "could not find disk HD".  The second format worked.  80% of the way through the 3rd. pass, I got these messages:  "Creating a secondary temporary file  Mounting disk  Error: -69847:  Couldn't create temporary file  Underlying error:  1:  POSIX reports:  Operation not permitted.  Next time, I will set LEVEL to either 0 or 1.